# How can I change password for my Exchange settings

Tags: settings, exchange, password

Due to corporate policy, I was forced to change my domain password, which impacts also the access to Exchange server.
Now I need to update that password also in my Android phone (Galaxy S, Android 2.1.1), but I can't find the settings in the phone.
Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Settings - Account and Sync - <your exchange account>' - Account settings - (scroll down) Incoming settings' - password field`.

On my Samsung Galaxy S - running Froyo 2.2.1

Comment: Thanks, @Edelcom, that was easy...
The problem was that the fields below has pixel or two of identation, so "Incoming settings" look like chapter label, and I haven't tried to click on it.

Comment: I had exact same problem, did not see it was itself a field to edit.

Answer (score 2):

The phone *should* prompt you for the new password once it gets an error back from Exchange.  If it doesn't - you can try removing the account and re-adding it on `Menu -> Settings -> Accounts and sync` page.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung Galaxy S2...same solution touch click "Incoming Settings"  which looks like a label rather than a field

Answer (score 1):

Samsung version 7.0 answer: Apps - email - settings - click account - exchange server settings

This was way more difficult to figure out than it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

In Samsung Galaxy S2:

> Settings > Accounts and Sync > (Select your Exchange email) > Account Settings > (Select your added account) > Scroll down to Sub heading "Sever Settings" > Exchange server settings

Under that heading is:

- Domain\User name
- Password
- Exchange Server Settings

The phone does NOT prompt you for a new password. That would be nice if it did, instead of continually updating you with notifications that it could not connect to the Exchange server.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your account setting will allow you to access your e-mail, *but* will not reset the Google account synchronization.

After you update your passwords in the accounts of the security section then open the Playstore application.

The Playstore application will then notice your change of password and will prompt you for the new one.

Give the new password and that's it.

Comment: That looks like you are talking about the *Google Account* password. OP is asking for his *Exchange* password. AFAIK, the two are not related. Did I get something wrong? What does the "Playstore application" have to do with Exchange accounts, and why should it prompt for a new one?